# redraw pixel to original color (transaprent) in uiimage

Tags: ios, swift

i have an image and draw line through the image. The image has transparent background and line has pink color. How can i remove exceeding line, please? I have no idea how. I didn't find anything about this.

[image]

I will be glad for any help. Thank you